# UPDATE age column in DB everyday based on JavaScript result

Tags: javascript, mysql, sql

I am trying to update age everyday at midnight.
Currently, the table has three columns: id, DOB and age.
The user inputs DOB (YYYYMMDD format), from which I calculate the age and insert into the DB.

[image]

The JS code to calculate the age is:

```
   calculateAge(birthDate) {
        let year = birthDate.slice(0,4);
        let month = birthDate.slice(4,6);
        let day = birthDate.slice(6);

        birthDate = year + '/' + month + '/' + day;

        birthDate = new Date(birthDate);
        let today = new Date();

        var years = (today.getFullYear() - birthDate.getFullYear());

        if (today.getMonth() < birthDate.getMonth() || 
            today.getMonth() == birthDate.getMonth() && today.getDate() < birthDate.getDate()) {
            years--;
        }
    
        return years;
    }
```

Once it becomes 2021/02/11, how do I make sure that the age for id=2 changes to 31?

My thoughts on the necessary steps are :

1. Get all the data

```
let data = connection.query('SELECT * FROM my_table_name');
```

2. calculate the new age

```
for(let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
  data[i].age = calculateAge(data[i].DOB);
}
```

3. Insert the updated age back into the DB

```
CREATE EVENT update_age
    ON SCHEDULE
      EVERY 1 DAY 
      STARTS '2021-02-11 00:00:00'
    DO
UPDATE my_table_name 
SET age = ?  
WHERE 
... ;
```

Step 3 is where I am currently stuck.
First of all, I need Javascript to run steps 1 and 2 on a daily basis...How would I go about implementing this? Second, since I am basically updating the whole database, I do not know what the condition statement should be..in other words, how do I tell the db to SET age = 31 where id = 2?

Comment: Change `DOB` column to **proper date format**. Any valid reason why the date value has to be like that? And I second the opinion to extract age using query instead of storing it in db.

Answer (score 2):

Storing age in the database overcomplicates this and could result in issues if, for example, the daily job to update the age fails to run.

I would remove the age column from the database altogether, and simply calculate the age from the date of birth when you query the data.